# Why do the balance sheets of some large firms not balance?

Tags: investing, accounting, balance-sheet

I'm working my way through some accounting textbook and struggling to understand why some balance sheets on Yahoo Finance don't balance, as in:

total assets - total liabilities != total shareholders equity

Take for example https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/balance-sheet?p=AAPL - it balances perfectly.

But some dont: neither https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CHK/balance-sheet?p=CHK , https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BABA/balance-sheet?p=BABA nor https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BHC/balance-sheet?p=BHC balance.

Could anyone please explain why?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your math on your AAPL link again. 134,047 Equity + 241,272 Liabilities = 375,319 Assets. I think you might be looking at 'Net Tangible Assets' instead of Equity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a flaw in the normalized data set.  For CHK, If you look at their raw [2017 annual report](http://www.chk.com/media/publications/annual-report), you'll see that everything balances. The difference seems to be treasury stock (1,671,000) and non-controlling interests (124,000), and their treasury stock is off by about 30 (88 vs 57). If you add those to shareholder equity, you get a total of -372, which causes the statement to balance.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Really appreciated. I just assumed yahoo wouldn't have data issues on 3 major companies like alibaba, valeant and chesapeake.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a data error. Given the name of the financial statement, you know something is wrong when it doesn’t add up.

Check out the same tickers on investing.com/marketwatch.com and the BS for those add up.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be the handling of "minority interest".  I did the math on BHC.

For 2017:  Liabilities of $31,553k + minority interest of $95k + stockholder equity of $5,849k = $37,497k.  Which matches the total assets.

For 2016: Liabilities of $40,271k + minority interest of $106k + stockholder equity of $3,152k = $43,529k.  Which matches the total assets.

I have learned something new today about how to read the balance sheet.  Thanks!

Comment: It's not just minority interests. Their data for CHK is wrong for preferred stock and treasury shares as well.

Comment: I too can't make CHK's balance sheet add up.  For that matter, I can't make their income statement add up either.  I'd avoid CHK like the plague.

Comment: It balances if you make the adjustments in my answer. It's not CHK's fault - it's Yahoo's.